# Is there a name for this type of CES look-alike utility function?

Tags: utility, ces-function

I do not know whether the following utility functions are used a lot but I was wondering whether there was a common name for this type CES like utility function

$$u(z) = \left[  \left( \sum_{j \in J_1} z_{j}^{\alpha_1}\right)^{\rho/\alpha_1} + \left(\sum_{j \in J_2} z_{j}^{\alpha_2}\right)^{\rho/\alpha_2} \right]^{1/\rho},$$

perhaps it is simply an instance of the CES?

The utility function is defined over two non-overlapping groups $J_1$ and $J_2$ of goods $z_j$. The goods from the two groups are weighted diffrently in the inner CES part by $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it can be found as "nested CES"

See for example:

[Nested CES](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/23938/nested-ces-production-function?rq=1)

Comment: I think you are right. Do you have any references for it?

Comment: I unfortunately don't have much experience with the function. The following link looks familiar, so it is possible I referenced this in the past: https://www.gamsworld.org/mpsge/debreu/ces.pdf

Comment: That looks interesting (and tedious). I will accept the answer and maybe edit it later to add a reference if I find one.